# Thinkpad USB Dock 3.0 screens and network stops working after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1703

As the title says my dock stopped working after a Windows Update this morning. Keyboard and mouse works but not RJ45 and no screen. Has anyone experienced this?

What I have tried:

Downloaded latest drivers from Lenovo:

https://support.lenovo.com/se/sv/solutions/pd023761

When this did not work I tried updating from DisplayLink:

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads

Info:

> Thinkpad USB Dock 3.0 DU9019D1

Current OS version:

> Windows 10 Pro Version 1703 OS Build 15063.483

Comment: Latest Drivers from Lenovo of DOCK supports till Windows10 build 14396,  Currently you are using Display Link Graphics Driver Version 8.0.762.0 drivers wont be supported for windows 10 build 1703. I think you should make try on the Third Party Driver update which may help you. Please let us know your driver version and also Hardware ID of the Driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

I have a Elitebook 840, found out Gen version by looking at my CPU. In my case it is a i7-5600U which is a Gen 2. Downloaded the latest Bios drivers from HP and after upgrade everything worked:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-840-g2-notebook-pc/7343202

[image]